# Concatenating a string and numeric variable

Tags: vba, string-concatenation, sap-gui

I need some help here, I have a command for SAP GUI script in VBA where I just need to change a number am each line, is there a way to have just one line and create a loop? num1 = 5, num2 = 9, num3 = 10

```
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/chk[2,5]").Selected = True
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/chk[2,9]").Selected = True
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/chk[2,10]").Selected = True
```

what I hope

```
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/chk[2,numX]").Selected = True
```

Comment: The question is only about concatenating string and numeric variable, it's not specific to SAP GUI. I have changed the title and tags accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way using a For Each loop.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim vNums() As Variant
    vNums = Array(5, 9, 10)
    
    Dim vNum As Variant
    For Each vNum In vNums
        session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/chk[2," & vNum & "]").Selected = True
    Next vNum
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

for example:

```
For numx = 5 To 13 Step 4
    If numx = 13 Then numx = 10
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/chk[2," & cstr(numx) & "]").Selected = True
next
```

Regards, ScriptMan