# Connection Between SAP GUI and VBA

Tags: excel, vba, string-concatenation, sap-gui, sap-erp

I need some help with a macro in VBA. It connects to SAP GUI and performs a series of repetitive actions that would take days to be done manually.

I don't understand anything of the SAP GUI Scripting language. I need to know how I can use a variable instead of `[1,0]`, so when the loop runs it uses the variable increment. The screen is SAP ECC `IW32` for maintenance orders.

My knowledge in SAP GUI Scripting language is nil.

Below is the VBA code.

```
' Sua rotina continua aqui.
Sub CONEXÃO()
    Dim SAP, SAPGUI, Connections, cntConnection, i, Connection, RetVal
    'Parametros
    On Error GoTo erro
    Set SAP = GetObject("SAPGUI")
    Set SAPGUI = SAP.GetScriptingEngine()
    Set Connections = SAPGUI.Connections()
    cntConnection = Connections.Count()
    Set Connection = SAPGUI.Connections(CLng(i))

    'Check Conexão
    If IsObject(Connection) Then
        ConnectionExists = vbTrue
    Else
        ConnectionExists = vbFalse
erro:
        RetVal = Shell("C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\saplogon.exe")   ' Execute o Programa.
        Set xl = CreateObject("excel.application")
        While xl.Ready = False
        Wend

        Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
        Set SapApp = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
        Set Connection = SapApp.OpenConnection("01 [BRF] - SAP ECC Produção -->Logon Automático<---", True)
        Set SapCon = SapApp.Children(0)
        Set session = SapCon.Children(0)


        'session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
        'session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-MANDT").Text = "mandante"
        'session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-BNAME").Text = "usuário"
        'session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/pwdRSYST-BCODE").Text = "senha"
        'session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0

        'Set session = Nothing
        'connection.CloseSession ("ses[0]")
        'Set connection = Nothing
        'Set sap = Nothing
    End If
End Sub

Sub Macro1()
    Application.Run "CONEXÃO"

    Dim App, Connection, session As Object
    Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
    Set App = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
    Set Connection = App.Children(0)
    Set session = Connection.Children(0)

    Dim i, x As Long

    i = 2
    x = 0
    While Planilha1.Cells(i, "B") <> ""

        ORDEM = Planilha1.Cells(i, 2)
        CPP = Planilha1.Cells(i, 3)
        QUANTIDADE = Planilha1.Cells(i, 4)
        OPERACAO = Planilha1.Cells(i, 5)
        APROVADOR = Planilha1.Cells(i, 6)
        CONTA = Planilha1.Cells(i, 7)
        GESTOR = Planilha1.Cells(i, 8)
        TIPO = Planilha1.Cells(i, 9)
        CONTRATO = Planilha1.Cells(i, 10)
        ITEMC = Planilha1.Cells(i, 11)
        
        Do While i <= 2
            session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
            session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/niw32"
            session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
            session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtCAUFVD-AUFNR").Text = ORDEM
            session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtCAUFVD-AUFNR").caretPosition = 12
            session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
            session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB_ALL:SAPLCOIH:3001/ssubSUB_LEVEL:SAPLCOIH:1100/tabsTS_1100/tabpMUEB").Select
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB_ALL:SAPLCOIH:3001/ssubSUB_LEVEL:SAPLCOIH:1101/tabsTS_1100/tabpMUEB/ssubSUB_AUFTRAG:SAPLCOMK:3020/tblSAPLCOMKTCTRL_3020/ctxtRESBD-MATNR[1,0]").Text = CPP
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB_ALL:SAPLCOIH:3001/ssubSUB_LEVEL:SAPLCOIH:1101/tabsTS_1100/tabpMUEB/ssubSUB_AUFTRAG:SAPLCOMK:3020/tblSAPLCOMKTCTRL_3020/txtRESBD-MENGE[4,0]").Text = "1"
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB_ALL:SAPLCOIH:3001/ssubSUB_LEVEL:SAPLCOIH:1101/tabsTS_1100/tabpMUEB/ssubSUB_AUFTRAG:SAPLCOMK:3020/tblSAPLCOMKTCTRL_3020/txtRESBD-MENGE[4,0]").SetFocus
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB_ALL:SAPLCOIH:3001/ssubSUB_LEVEL:SAPLCOIH:1101/tabsTS_1100/tabpMUEB/ssubSUB_AUFTRAG:SAPLCOMK:3020/tblSAPLCOMKTCTRL_3020/txtRESBD-MENGE[4,0]").caretPosition = 18
        session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
        session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/txtRCM01-VORNR").Text = OPERACAO
        session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/txtRCM01-VORNR").caretPosition = 2
        session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 0
        session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtVG_SAKNR").Text = CONTA
        session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtVG_SAKNR").caretPosition = 6
        session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[13]").press
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/chkEBAN-WEUNB").Selected = False
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtEBAN-AFNAM").Text = "433004"
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtEBAN-BEDNR").Text = APROVADOR
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtEBAN-EKORG").Text = "0001"
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtEBAN-EKORG").SetFocus
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtEBAN-EKORG").caretPosition = 4
        session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
    Wend
```

Comment: Instead of "...-MATNR[1,0]" you would do something like "...-MATNR" & yourVariable.

Comment: For information, here you miss VBA knowledge about concatenating text and variable, not about SAP GUI Scripting. This question has been already asked and answered.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenating a string and numeric variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73211986/concatenating-a-string-and-numeric-variable)

Answer (score 2):

For example

```
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
```

Here "wnd[0]" is just a String, so you could do something like (eg)

```
Dim i As Long

i = 2
session.findById("wnd[" & i & "]").maximize
```

And if you needed to increment that in a loop:

```
For i = 0 To 5
    session.findById("wnd[" & i & "]").maximize
Next i
```

or multiple variables

```
"...-MATNR[1,0]" >> "-MATNR[" & i & "," & j & "]"
```